# How can I update a particular QAbstractListModel item?

Tags: qlist, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractlistmodel

I have derived a class FeedItemViewModel from QAbstractListModel.
I have implemented a method which adds items in the list model but I do not know how too update an item which has a specific id.

Here is the code:

```
void FeedItemViewModel::addFeedItem(FeedItem* feedItem)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_feedItems.append(feedItem);
    endInsertRows();
}

void FeedItemViewModel::updateFeedItem(FeedItem* feedItem)
{
    int id = feedItem->id();
    auto iter = std::find_if(m_feedItems.begin(), m_feedItems.end(),
                         [id](FeedItem* item)
                         {
                            return item->id() == id;
                         });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

```
void FeedItemViewModel::updateFeedItem(FeedItem* feedItem)
{
    int id = feedItem->id();
    auto iter = std::find_if(m_feedItems.begin(), m_feedItems.end(),
                             [id](FeedItem* item)
    {
            return item->id() == id;
    });

    if(iter != m_feedItems.end())
    {
        int indx = m_feedItems.indexOf(*iter);
        m_feedItems[indx] = feedItem;
        dataChanged(index(indx), index(indx));
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use `emit dataChanged(...)`. It is a signal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just updating an item and not replacing it, you could simplify by finding the pointer itself instead of using the id property

```cpp
void FeedItemViewModel::updateFeedItem(FeedItem *feedItem){
    int indx = m_feedItems.indexOf(feedItem);
    if(indx != -1){
        dataChanged(index(indx), index(indx));
    }
}
```